# Combine Crystal Reports and WebAPI, is it possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, crystal-reports

I have a .NET WebAPI project, and I have added a rpt Report file to it. How can I add to that a Crystal Report WebViewer component?

What I have come up with so far:

```
public class ReportController: ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public CrystalReportViewer GetReport()
    {
        CrystalReportViewer reportViewer = new CrystalReportViewer();
        ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
        reportDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("CrystalReport1.rpt"));
        reportViewer.ReportSource = reportDocument;
        return reportViewer;
    }
}
```

The error I get during compile is

> The type or namespace name "CrystalReportViewer" could not be found.

although I have in my reference list:

- CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
- CrystalDecisions.ReportSource
- CrystalDecisions.Shared

However, I am not sure how the Report can pass through an API. Can someone with more knowledge shed some light on this?

Comment: What you are asking for makes zero sense. What exactly do you expect to happen? If you want  an html page I think it still only supports [WebForms](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/how-to-create-crystal-reports-in-asp-net-webforms/) only and if you want a pdf you can do [that](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-crystal-report-with-asp-net-mvc-5/) as well.

Comment: @FilipCordas So I guess I should ask the question "How do I re-implement an existing VB6 WinForms CrystalReport application in an existing WebAPI Application".

Comment: Probably, but I think there is a bunch of stuff out there on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now creating PDF or XLSX as a stream, copying it into a memory stream and send that content back as base64 encoded string. The base64 is then loaded as a data URL into an iframe.

Backend:

```
[HttpGet]
public AjaxAnswer<string> GetReport(...)
{
    ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
    ...
    Stream s = reportDocument.ExportToStream(ExportFormat.FileFormat);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    s.CopyTo(ms);
    return new AjaxAnswer() {
        success = true,
        data = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray()
    };
}
```

Frontend:

```
form.submit({
    ...
    success: function(form, operation) {
        pnl.setLoading(false);
        var pdfBase64 = Ext.decode(operation.response.responseText, true).data;
        if(pdfBase64) {
            if(!Ext.isIE && !Ext.isEdge && !btn.isXLS) {
                document.querySelector(".iframe-report-pdf").src = "data:application/pdf;base64," + pdfBase64;
            } else {
                var type = (btn.isXLS?'application/xlsx':'application/pdf');
                var filename = (btn.report || btn.text)+(btn.isXLS?'.xls':'.pdf');

                Ext.Download(Ext.B64ToBlob(pdfBase64, type), filename, type);
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: Offtopic, but how well this solution scales? With older CR versions we have done something similar, it puts nasty stress on web server; for our new API design we just excluded CR support (so far).

Comment: @Arvo It does not scale very well, but the PDFs are only created (and then printed) by a single person at a time, usually once or twice a month.